# duda roles laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Tengo el siguiente codigo en una plantilla blade, y he dado permisos de admin a todo el menu, la cuestion es... que puedo hacer si quiero darle permisos a otros dos usuarios a ese mismo menu? hay alguna forma de de hacer esto?

```html
@extends('layouts.layout')
@section('content')

<link rel="stylesheet" href="{!! asset('css/estilos.css') !!}">
 <div id="principal02"><br>
  <table border="0" Cellspacing=0>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="6" align="center">Herramientas Administrativas</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    @if(Auth::user()->hasRole('admin'))
 <td><a href="{{ route('registros.index') }}"><img src="{{ asset('images/01.png') }}" alt="mi foto"></a></td> 
 <td><a href="{{ route('ecuentas.index') }}"><img src="{{ asset('images/05.png') }}" alt="mi foto"></td> 
 <td><a href="{{ route('usuario.create') }}"><img src="{{ asset('images/06.png') }}" alt="mi foto"></a></td>
 <td><a href="{{ route('usuario.index') }}"><img src="{{ asset('images/02.png') }}" alt="mi foto"></a></td>
 <td><a href="{{ route('cuenta.tareas') }}"><img src="{{ asset('images/03.png') }}" alt="mi foto"></a></td>
 <td><a href="{{ route('cuenta.revisar') }}"><img src="{{ asset('images/04.png') }}" alt="mi foto"></a></td>
 @endif
  </tr>
</tr><td>Nueva Cuenta</td> <td>Editar Cuenta</td><td>Agregar Usuario </td> <td>Buscar Usuario</td><td>Asignar Tarea</td>  <td>Revisar Avances</td>  </tr>
   
  </table>
</form>

 </div>


@endsection
```